# Symbolic logic operator "implication" to logical gates

Tags: logic-gates

I need to translate a *symbolic operator* to a logical gates circuit.

Following the table that the *symbolic operator* has:

`P Q    Result
1 1    1
1 0    0
0 1    1
0 0    1`

Any idea how can I make it?

This is a draft of solution

[image]

Comment: What do YOU think it should be?

Comment: You have a three times 1 on the output and one time a zero. That means your output stage should be an OR gate. After finding this out, check which input you have to invert on the input stage to match the truth table. You are done.

Comment: @Janka Why OR gate? the first solution that comes into my mind is an AND and two inverters (surely can be done with OR too)...

Comment: Please guy do not run :)
I tried a couple of solution but I hadn't find those results

Comment: So show some of the "solutions" and we might try and help you to  understand what their problem is.

Comment: An OR gate because you have three times a 1 on the output and one time a 0. If you use it, you see an inverter on P gives you the input you need.

Comment: @Janka I hadn't get it. Could you please draw it?

Comment: A nand gate with an inverter on one of the inputs seems like the simplest/most basic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution for such puzzles is counting the one and zeroes at the output:

- all zero or all one → trivial
- one zero and three ones → OR gate (or NAND gate)
- one one and three zeroes → AND gate (or NOR gate)
- two zeroes and two ones → trival (copy P or Q) or XOR or XNOR gate

---

```
P Q   R
1 1   1
1 0   0
0 1   1
0 0   1
```

Three ones. So we have an OR gate at the output. Let's take a look at the case where R is zero: An OR gate needs two zeroes to create a zero. So we have to invert P before feeding it into the gate.

```
P  -P Q   R
1   0 1   1
1   0 0   0
0   1 1   1
0   1 0   1
```

Let's order the lines the "normal" way:

```
P  -P Q   R
1   0 0   0
1   0 1   1
0   1 0   1
0   1 1   1
```

I think you can see now the solution is inverting the P input, then feeding -P and Q into an OR gate.

Comment: I made the circuit but I think I made some mistakes

Comment: Why to you have an AND gate in there? You don't need it. You need a single OR gate and one inverter in the P line.

Comment: ok... done thank you